# It might be a runner

Tags: meaning

What does it mean if somebody says: "It might be a runner"?

Example context:
"I have to check with my boss, but I reckon it might be a runner."

Comment: The standard idiom is [*It might be a **goer***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+might+be+a+goer%22) (110 hits in Google Books, as opposed to just 3 for [*It might be a runner*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+might+be+a+runner%22))

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom based on a metaphor of betting on horse racing, with a runner meaning "a good runner", which stands a good chance of winning, and is therefore worthy of consideration for betting on.

It means that something might be a good option, basically:  it's like saying

*"I have to check with my boss, but I believe that we will go with this option."*